# Spreadsheets for Matlab

Tags: spreadsheet, matlab

I was wondering if there was a way to directly write a spreadsheets in Matlab, or if someone had published a Matlab add-on that specifically introduced spreadsheets?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the .csv format in order to export MATLAB data to a spreadsheet.
You can write a matrix to a csv file using the the [csvwrite](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvwrite.html) function. The following code writes matrix M to a csv file in your workspace:

```
csvwrite(filename,M)
```

You can easily import the csv file to excel, numbers, google docs etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write an Excel spreadsheet, you can do so directly with the xlswrite function.

Example:

```
filename = "spreadsheet.xlsx";
data = 1:5;
xlswrite(filename,data);   % Writes matrix 'data' to the sheet starting at cell A1.
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable viewing window gives some spreadsheet functionality (e.g. paste from excel).